# How to make img within div to shuffle randomly?

Tags: javascript, image, shuffle

I am trying to make memory game and have been struggled to make images that are in div, to randomly shuffle. I would like to hear some advices and that would be really helpful for me to finish my first project. I do not know about Jquery so it would be nice to have answers using just vanilla Javascript. Thank you.

I have tried:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="img-container" id="container-1">
        <img src="/image/elephant.jpg" class="hidden" />
      </div>
      <div class="img-container" id="container-2">
        <img src="/image/koalas.jpg" class="hidden" />
      </div>
      <div class="img-container" id="container-3">
        <img src="/image/lion.jpg" class="hidden" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="img-container" id="container-4">
        <img src="/image/elephant.jpg" class="hidden" />
      </div>
      <div class="img-container" id="container-5">
        <img src="/image/koalas.jpg" class="hidden" />
      </div>
      <div class="img-container" id="container-6">
        <img src="/image/lion.jpg" class="hidden" />
      </div>
```

```
"use strict";

const container = document.querySelectorAll(".img-container");
const image = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden");

let imgArr = ["/image/elephant.jpg", "/image/koalas.jpg", "/image/lion.jpg"];

// Flip cards
for (let i = 0; i < container.length; i++)
  container[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    image[i].classList.remove("hidden");
  });

// Shuffle cards
const shuffle = function (imgArr) {
  for (let i = imgArr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [imgArr[i], imgArr[j]] = [imgArr[j], imgArr[i]];
  }
  return imgArr;
};
console.log(shuffle(imgArr));
```

It does shuffle the array in the console but does not affect the actual visualization.

Comment: add how are you adding them to your HTMLdom?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use an array that stores your images, then loop through it in javascript. This way you can shuffle the array before displaying it in the DOM.

```
images = ['image1.png', 'image2.png'...]
```

Example of shuffling an array:

```
images.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
```

You can read more [here](https://moderncodr.com/shuffling-an-array-of-images-and-display-it-in-the-dom/) on how to display it in the DOM

Comment: he's already storing and shuffling the array, thats not the problem

Answer (score 0):

The image elements have set `src` values which you are not changing after the shuffle.

Here is your `img` element:

```
<img src='image/lions.jpg' />
```

and here is your `imgArr`:

```
imgArr = ["/image/elephant.jpg", "/image/koalas.jpg", "/image/lion.jpg"]
```

There is no co-relation between the actual `img` elements and the `imgArr` array.

What you can do is, change the `src` attribute of the `img` elements after calling `shuffle`. Something like this:

```
const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
.
.
.
const shuffleArr = function (imgArr) {
  for (let i = imgArr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [imgArr[i], imgArr[j]] = [imgArr[j], imgArr[i]];
  }
  return imgArr;
};

const shuffleInUI = function () {
  shuffleArr(imgArr);

  images.forEach((img, index) => {
    let calcIndex = index >= imgArr.length ? ((index + 1)/2) - 1 : index
    img.src = imgArr[calcIndex]
  })
};

shuffleInUI();
```